# Sending mail by button

Tags: email, button, google-sheets, sendmail

I want to send e-mail after confirmation box. I make a button and push after i should choice yes or no. If NO nothing do. If yes i want to start to SendAnEmail.

Please help me. How can I start the function SendAnEmail?

Thank you.

```
  function SendAnEmail() {

  var email = 'my@mail.com'

  var subject = 'mySubject';

  var body = 'body of mail';

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}

function test(){
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var ret = ui.alert('Do you want send e-mail?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 if(ret == ui.Button.YES)
{GmailApp.sendEmail}
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: is this javascript?  If so,  I would add that tag to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are almost there

The only thing you need to do is to call function `SendAnEmail()` when the button `Yes` is pressed.

So:

```
function test(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ret = ui.alert('Do you want send e-mail?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(ret == ui.Button.YES){
    SendAnEmail()
  }
}
```

Comment: when i tried with SendAnEmail i forgot to put brackets (). Thank you!